# iOS - How To Drag a Cell From One Collection View To Another

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I implemented the drag & drop inside one `UICollectionView`, there is no problem in that. But how can I get the cell out of one `UICollectionView` and put it to another? As much as possible I want some sample code written in Objective-C. Thanks!

Comment: What is "OC Version's guide?"

Comment: How about one collection view with two sections?

Comment: I write  the project by  object -c language rather than swift.So I hope get some help about Object -c!